# Android SQLiteOpenHelper filling tables

Tags: android, sqlite

Tell me please, how SQLiteOpenHelper fills tables after restarting app?
I have metho onCreate() and onUpdate() and by tutorials both of them are just work with metadata of tables.

I mean how usualy android preserves the same state of db after restarting app?. What I have to do in order to save data and have them after restarting. Not to have only empty tables?

Comment: At what are you referring when saying *fills tables after restarting app*?

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in the **onPause()** method, and restore the data in the **onResume()** method.

It's always helpful to read the lifecycle diagram at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: If I understand you right, it is applicable to activity. I`m talking about restarting hall app. After restarting  activity my datas preserved, but restarting hall program makes my db empty.

Comment: If you save the data in your main-activity's onPause() (and commit your database) this should work.